# console.log(-1) still returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I have my js code for homework here. I have an `if` statement that should return -1 in console when the input is not a number but instead of returning -1 it returns NaN. Can anybody help me with this?

```
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood) {
    // IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!

    var total = avgFood*numAnimals;
    
        if ((Number(numAnimals || avgFood) < 0) && (isNaN(numAnimals || avgFood))) {
                console.log(-1);
            } else {
                return total
            }
                
    }
    calculateFoodOrder()
```

Comment: Because `NaN` is not smaller than 0

Comment: I doubt that your `if` condition does what you might think it does.

Comment: @Andreas I dont understand what you mean

Comment: `not a number` how is that defined? In your example you filter numbers smaller than zero, which by definition are numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default values in your function are 'undefined'. That's why javascript is showing NaN. Define default values to avoid this. For example:

```
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals = 0, avgFood = 0) {

    var total = avgFood*numAnimals;

    if ((Number(numAnimals || avgFood) < 0) && (isNaN(numAnimals || avgFood))) {
        console.log(-1);
    } else {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am fully aware of this however the question tells me that i cannot change the function part. and when i tried your example the autograder saw the ` = 0 ` as a syntax error

Comment: Can you check for 'undefined' inside your function? If one of your variables is undefined then: console.log(-1)

Comment: the autograder automatically defines a value and thats the reason your code came out as a syntax error. it tried to do calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals = 0 = 5, avgFood = 0 = 6)

Comment: NaN is not less than 0, it still gets NaN if you give two strings as parameters.

Comment: Then the autograder is outdated, because the `= 0` would be valid ES6 code. (Not ES5 though.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly, you merely have to check both parameters for not being `NaN` using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Your sample code does not work because any comparison with `NaN` returns `false` and thus `Number(numAnimals || avgFood) < 0` is never going to be `true`. [Check here for details on NaN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

```js
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood){
  //REM: Default result
  let tResult = -1;

  //REM: Check if both paramters are not NaN
  //REM: Be aware that whitespaces and empty strings validate to zero
  if(
    !isNaN(numAnimals) &&
    !isNaN(avgFood)
  ){
    tResult = Number(avgFood) * Number(numAnimals)
  };
  
  return tResult
};

//REM: Default test case
console.log(calculateFoodOrder());

;document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  console.log(
    calculateFoodOrder(
      document.getElementById('innumAnimals').value,
      document.getElementById('inavgFood').value
    )
  )
};
```

```html
<input type = 'text' value = '' id = 'innumAnimals' placeholder = 'numAnimals' />
<input type = 'text' value = '' id = 'inavgFood' placeholder = 'avgFood' />
<button>do</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not confuse yourself with caveats if you are a beginner. You should assign to itself after converting to number, then judge if it's a NaN value or less then zero just like this,

```js
function calculateFoodOrder(numAnimals, avgFood) {
    // IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!
    numAnimals = Number(numAnimals);
    avgFood = Number(avgFood);

    var total = avgFood * numAnimals;

    if (isNaN(numAnimals) || isNaN(avgFood) || numAnimals < 0 || avgFood < 0 ) {
        console.log(-1);
    } else {
        return total
    }

}
calculateFoodOrder()
```